# Using Python logging with impersonation

Tags: python, impersonation

I am in a situation to write logs to server where end user will not have write permissions to server where i need to write logs.

If i want to use impersonate how it can be done, as logging will be in so many places in the code i cannot impersonate login and write log and impersonate logoff.

Is there a workaround that logging module itself can use impersonate funmctionality.

Comment: Why does the logging depend on the end user? Your app itself should *always* have permission to write logs, and *only* the app has permission. The app should just get the user info and include it in the log.

Comment: these are the tools that end user will run in there login, without imperdonate how it can be achived.